# Renaming a SQL Database using PowerShell does not rename the physical filename

Tags: sql, powershell

I am creating a PowerShell function which can rename a database.

This is working quite well:

```
    $sqlServer = "MySqlServer"
    $currentDbName = "MyDB"
    $sqlConnectionString = "Server='$sqlserver';Database='$currentDbName';Integrated Security=True"
    $sqlQueries = `
        "ALTER DATABASE [$currentDbName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE",`
        "EXEC sp_renamedb '$currentDbName', '$NewName'",`
        "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] SET MULTI_USER", `
        "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $currentDbName, NEWNAME = $NewName)", `
        "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $($currentDbName)_Log, NEWNAME = $($NewName)_Log)"
    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($sqlConnectionString)
    try {
        $conn.Open()
        $sqlQueries | % {
            $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
            $cmd.CommandText = $_
            $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            Write-Host "    Executed: $_" -ForegroundColor Gray
        }
    }
    catch{
        $actualError = $error[0]

        throw $actualError
    }
    finally{
        if($conn) {
            $conn.Close()
            $conn.Dispose()
        }
    }
```

This script rename the database and the datafile (assuming there is only one datafile).

But this script does not rename the physical name of the files and does not supports renaming several data files.

How can also rename the physical files of the database?

Please note that the database schema is not in my control, I can't add stored procedure in the DB.

**[Edit]** The script runs remotely, not in the SQL Server box.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx) you need to include the FILENAME clause

```
MODIFY FILE ( NAME = logical_file_name, FILENAME = ' new_path/os_file_name ' )
```

I believe the flow would be:

1. Rename the database and datafile names
2. Take the database offline
3. Rename the physical files
4. update the database filenames to point at the new physical files
5. Bring the database back online

I have had a go at updating your script to how I think it should read, I don't have anywhere to test this, so make sure you are testing this in a 'safe' place.

```
$sqlServer = "MySqlServer"
$currentDbName = "MyDB"
$sqlConnectionString = "Server='$sqlserver';Database='$currentDbName';Integrated Security=True"

$PhysicalLocal = "C:\Data\"
$PhysicalUNC = "\\$sqlserver\C$\Data\"

$sqlQueries = `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$currentDbName] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE",`
    "EXEC sp_renamedb '$currentDbName', '$NewName'",`
    "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] SET MULTI_USER", `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $currentDbName, NEWNAME = $NewName)", `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $($currentDbName)_Log, NEWNAME = $($NewName)_Log)", `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$currentDbName] SET offline"

$sqlQueriesRename = `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $NewName, FILENAME = $($PhysicalLocal\$NewName).mdf", `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $($NewName)_Log, FILENAME = $($PhysicalLocal\$NewName)_Log.ldf)", `
    "ALTER DATABASE [$currentDbName] SET online"

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($sqlConnectionString)
try {
    $conn.Open()

    # Rename the database, leave in offline state
    $sqlQueries | % {
        $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
        $cmd.CommandText = $_
        $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Write-Host "    Executed: $_" -ForegroundColor Gray
    }

    # Rename the physical files
    Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalUNC -ChildPath $($currentDbName).mdf) $($NewName).mdf
    Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalUNC -ChildPath $($currentDbName)_Log.ldf) $($NewName)_Log.ldf

    # Rename the database files to match the physical ones
    $sqlQueriesRename | % {
        $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
        $cmd.CommandText = $_
        $cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Write-Host "    Executed: $_" -ForegroundColor Gray
    }
}
catch{
    $actualError = $error[0]
    throw $actualError
}
finally{
    if($conn) {
        $conn.Close()
        $conn.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: This can only apply if I'm working directly on the server, because I have to update the sql filesystem. I didn't precise that (I admit), but this script works remotely. But it may be the first part of the answer.

Comment: Could you use UNC for the remote physical rename?

Comment: I guess I may succeed in changing the file system remotly, either by working with the UNC path as you suggests, or maybe by remotely invoking a powershell command. Not easy though, because of security doors that have to be opened.

Comment: Yes, either that or xpcmdshell all need elevated/special privileges to work.

Comment: somehow these commands didn't work for me:
`Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalUNC -ChildPath $($currentDbName).mdf) $($NewName).mdf

    Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalUNC -ChildPath $($currentDbName)_Log.ldf) $($NewName)_Log.ldf`

I replaced them with:
`Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalLocal -ChildPath "$currentDbName.mdf") "$NewName.mdf" -Force

    Rename-Item $(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalLocal -ChildPath "$($currentDbName)_Log.ldf") "$($NewName)_Log.ldf" -Force` 
these seem to work ok

Comment: Also had problems with this syntax:
`"ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $NewName, FILENAME = $($PhysicalLocal\$NewName).mdf"`

this worked though: `"ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] MODIFY FILE (NAME = $NewName, FILENAME = '$(Join-Path -Path $PhysicalLocal -ChildPath $NewName).mdf')"`

and of course `"ALTER DATABASE [$NewName] SET online"` instead of `"ALTER DATABASE [$currentDbName] SET online"`